# GDB getting executable path from core file

Tags: gdb

Is there any GDB command to get executable file path?
Currently it shows

```
Core was generated by ./a.bin
```

But I don't want to grep the result. Is there a way to get generated path using GDB command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Core was generated by ./a.bin

Please note that most OSes have a rather short limit on the length of the executable path that can be recorded in the `NT_PRPSINFO` ELF note (on Linux, this is limited to 16 characters).

> Is there a way to get generated path using GDB command.

I don't believe so.

It is quite simple to write a program to find `PT_NOTE` segment in the `core`, then decode (variable sized) ELF notes, until you find the `NT_PRPSINFO` note, and then you can print the `pf_fname` member of `struct prpsinfo`.

But given that the info there may be truncated, it's not clear why you'd want to write such a program.